# How does the hurry package import work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, package

The `hurry` package collection provides several modules like [`hurry.filesize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.filesize) and [`hurry.workflow`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hurry.workflow) which can be installed separately each. How does the import of the `hurry` module work? I'm using Python 2.7

The directory structure in *site-packages/* is

```
site-packages/
    hurry/
        filesize/
            __init__.py
            filesize.py
            tests.py
            README.txt
    hurry.filesize-0.9-py2.7-nspkg.pth
    hurry.filesize-0.9-py2.7.egg-info/
        dependency_links.txt
        ...
```

There is no `__init__.py` in the *hurry/* folder, yet I can import it and it is treated as a builtin module.

```
>>> import hurry
>>> hurry
<module 'hurry' (built-in)>
```

How does this work? Why can I import `hurry` without there being an `__init__.py` file? How can I implement this functionality for my own packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the magic. This is the `__init__.py` file of the `hurry` package:

```
# this is a namespace package
try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    import pkgutil
    __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

And also important: In `setup.py`

```
setup(
    ...,
    packages=['foo.bar.ham'],
    namespace_packages=['foo', 'foo.bar'], # <<<
    ...
)
```

Comment: So the trick is, it installs `hurry.filesize` as a package and `hurry` as a namespace package?  You're using 'foo' and 'bar' here, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @florisla  Yes, that's it.